# Find number of records in a kafka topic without consuming those records

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am working on writing a test where before asserting on some things I need to wait until there are 2 records in the topic. I, then want to get these 2 records and do assertions on them. I can't seem to find a way to find number of records in a topic without actually consuming them.

Here is a brief on what i am trying to do. I am listening to an event published in topic "x". After consuming this event I publish a new event "abc" in the same topic "x". Now I want to do some assertions based on the published event "abc". In test i have a separate consumer subscribed to "x". So I should wait to assert things until i know there are 2 events for the consumer to consume

Comment: why not consuming them? what is the reason behind that requirement?

Comment: I am listening to an event published in topic "x". After consuming this event I publish a new event "abc" in the same topic "x". Now I want to do some assertions based on the published event "abc". In test i have a separate consumer subscribed to "x". So I should wait to assert things until i know there are 2 events for the consumer to consume.

Comment: 1) Why are you sending data to the same topic? Won't that just cause an infinite loop in the code? 2) Are you actually starting a Kafka server to test this? Try using MockProducer and MockConsumer, and expose the size of the data received by the consumer as a list of incoming events. For example, make an assertion in your code that guarantees you have two events. Let Kafka handle the fact that the producer "just works"

Answer (score 0):

Messages are not consumed per se. They are just delivered to every subscribed consumer group once but stay in the topic for future use. So you can "consume" them with a dedicated consumer group and perform your tests without worrying about other consumers.

Comment: Sorry for the vague question. Here is a brief on what i am trying to do. I am listening to an event published in topic "x". After consuming this event I publish a new event "abc" in the same topic "x". Now I want to do some assertions based on the published event "abc". In test i have a separate consumer subscribed to "x". So I should wait to assert things until i know there are 2 events for the consumer to consume

Comment: So this seems to be more of a testing problem? In this case, I suggest to repeatedly check if two messages arrived and perform your assertions then. You should use a timeout and consider the test failed if not both messages arrived in time. Have a look at Awaitility https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility/wiki/Usage for tests with timeouts.